# Reading String[] Array in a gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, gridview

I'm retrieving data from a mongodb database into a gridview, and I have a collection like this:

```
{"Name":"myName","Details":"bla bla bla","Notes":["note1","note2","note3"]}
{"Name":"myName","Details":"bla bla bla","Notes":["note1","note2"]}
{"Name":"myName","Details":"bla bla bla","Notes":["note1","note2","note3","note4"]}
```

my problem is gridview readind "Notes" value like that `System.String[]`

I'm using this code:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
mongo.Connect();
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("myDB");
var collection = db.GetCollection<MyCollection>();
var entity = collection.FindAll();
BindingList<MyCollection> entity2 = new BindingList<MongoDBTest.MyCollection>();

foreach (Book item in entity.Documents)
{
    entity2.Add(item);                                
}

GridView1.DataSource = entity2;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

how can I properly read "Notes" values?

Comment: `collection.FindAll();` returns the list of object or json string??

Comment: Returns a cursor that contains all of the documents in the collection.

Comment: whats the relation between your `MyCollection`, `Book` and `Document`, in you foreach you have book object how you can add to collection on `MyCollection` type

Comment: I'm sorry, "Book" is "MyCollection" and "Documents" gets the documents in that collection

Comment: it works properly for "Name" and "Details", my problem is in "Notes" only!!

Comment: yes because notes are collection (Array) so its applying the ToString() and showing that.  What you wanted to show in Notes cell?? as for each record you have multiple notes so which note you want to show??

Comment: I want to show all of them. something like `<ul>` to show all in one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a class for my entity `Book` like that:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public List<string> Notes { get; set; }
    public string NotesStr => String.Join(",", Notes);
}
```

and now I can retrieve `Notes` from `NotesStr` like that

```
Eval("NotesStr")
```